# Flyway: CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is EntityManagerFactory is closed

Tags: spring, flyway, spring-transactions

I need to write `flyway` migration for a `spring-boot-data-jpa` application with PostgreSQL.
All tests go well, but when I try to deploy the application, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
Migration failed !

Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy183.getTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.executeWithoutResult(TransactionOperations.java:67)
    at com.life.adapter.out.jpa.migration.V1689943999__Migrate_Documents.migrate(V1689943999__Migrate_Documents.kt:23)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.java.JavaMigrationExecutor.executeOnce(JavaMigrationExecutor.java:55)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:547)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:636)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:158)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManager(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:585)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:487)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:734)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy227.createNativeEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:485)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:410)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Help, please, what is the reason? I've been struggling with this problem for a few hours now.

Migration class:

```kotlin
@Component
class V1689943999__Migrate_Documents(
    @Lazy private val transactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager,
    @Lazy private val repository: EntityRepository
) : BaseJavaMigration() {

    override fun migrate(context: Context) {
        TransactionTemplate(transactionManager).executeWithoutResult {
            messageRepository.findAllByOrderByCreatedAt().use { entities ->
                entities.forEach { migrate(it) }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun migrate(entity: MessageEntity) {
        ... // some logic
        repository.save(entity)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Repository
interface MessageEntityRepository : JpaRepository<MessageEntity, UUID> {
    fun findAllByOrderByCreatedAt(): Stream<MessageEntity>

}
```

```
implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:8.5.13")
```

---

An interesting detail: if I replace repository method `findAllByOrderByCreatedAt()` (with `Stream`) with `findAll()` from `JpaRepository` (with just a collection), then everything works ok. But there can be a lot of records, therefore, in order to avoid `TimeoutException`, I want to use the method with `Stream<Entity>`. But maybe there is another way to perform this migration without the possibility of `TimeoutException`?

Comment: The same problem as the other issues you have with FLyway. You are injecting beans in classes that are used very early  in the process.

Comment: But after all, `@Lazy` must guarantee that the `val repository: EntityRepository` will be initialized only when it is directly accessed (that is, at the time of the migration process itself)

Comment: It turns out that there is no way to use `repository` for `flyway` migration?

Comment: Flyway starts, as mentioned in your other questions, very early in the process before a JPA is initialized to modify the schema. What if you would need to add 3 columns to a table and you also decided you would need JPA, it would fail miserably because the table doesn't match the entity yet. However you force early creation due to access JPA in the flyway migration. You are in a chicken/egg or catch-22 position here. The only thing you could use is the datasource, and you should use the one managed/used by Flyway.